# power query - find nearest time from multiple columns

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

| Time in | A | B | C | Custom |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10.15am | 7am | 8am | 11am |  |
| 7.45am | 7am | 8am | 11am |  |

Using power query, how to find which columns (A, B or C) is the closest to column "Time in"? Expected output:

| Time in | A | B | C | Custom |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10.15am | 7am | 8am | 11am | column C |
| 7.45am | 7am | 8am | 11am | column B |

edit: what i have worked till now
List.Min({ Number.Abs ( Duration.TotalMinutes ( [Time in] - [A])), ..........})

but this only returns the smallest difference not the column

Comment: Do you always have three columns _A,B_ and _C_ or can it happen that you have a fourth column _D_ with another time which you would like to compare with column _Time in_

Comment: ideally the solution should be for dynamic number of columns

Comment: Ok, sorry, I only can solve it for a fixed number. Another question: Would you like to see the value of the closest time or the name of the column (_A,B_ or _C_) in the column _Custom_

Comment: what would you do for a fixed number of columns? i'll try to learn from there

Answer (score 0):

What came to mind, dynamic number of columns,  was

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
ConvertToNumbers = List.Accumulate(Table.ColumnNames(Source),Source, (s,c)=>Table.TransformColumnTypes( s, {c,type number}, "en-US")),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(ConvertToNumbers , "Custom", each let z= [Time in] in List.Min(List.Transform(List.Skip(Record.ToList(_),1), each Number.Abs(_ - z)))),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Column", each Table.ColumnNames(Source){1+List.PositionOfAny(List.Skip(Record.ToList(_),1),{[Custom]+[Time in],[Time in]-[Custom]})}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom1",{"Custom"}),
ConvertToTime = List.Accumulate(Table.ColumnNames(Source),#"Removed Columns", (s,c)=>Table.TransformColumnTypes( s, {c,type time}, "en-US"))
in  ConvertToTime
```

[image]

Comment: this part- -> Number.Abs( Number.From(_) - z)

z is time format? would it be better to change all to numbers first?

Comment: got this msg - Expression.Error: We cannot apply operator - to types Number and Time

Comment: Everything needs to be  formatted as a number to start with.  To make it explicit, I'll edit my answer